# previous row element of array also getting updated

Tags: c++, arrays

> in this program i am separating integers from a character array which consists of a space between them

```
#include<iostream>     
#include<stdio.h>     
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0, t, l = 0, j, c, k, q = 0, num = 0;
    char ch[10][10];
    int ach[10][1];
    cout << "enter the number of test cases";
    cin >> t;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        cin.getline(ch[i], 9);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        num = 0;

        for (j = 0; ch[i][j] != '\0'; j++) //calculating length   
        {
            l = j;
        }
        l = l + 1;

        for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            if (ch[i][j] == ' ') //finding the space     
                c = j;
        }

        for (k = 0; k < c; k++) //taking first integer out of char array    
        {
            q = ch[i][k] - 48;    //parsing char to int
            num = (num * 10) + q;
        }
        cout << "\n previous row element " << ach[0][1] << "\n"; //checking the value    

        ach[i][0] = num; // this statement is updating the previous row's last element of the array    

        cout << "\n previous row element " << ach[0][1] << "\n"; //checking the value    
        cout << ach[i][0];

        num = 0;
        q = 0;
        for (k = c + 1; k < l; k++) //taking second element out of char array     
        {
            q = ch[i][k] - 48;     //parsing char to int
            num = (num * 10) + q;
        }

        ach[i][1] = num;
        cout << ach[i][1];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << ach[i][0] << "\t" << ach[i][1] << "\n"; //displaying the values       
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

> I have marked the code that is malfunctioning , it is updating the previous row's last element. please help.

Comment: Why not just use `istringstream` and `operator >>` to do this work?  In addition to that, why not use `std::string`?

Comment: See here: http://ideone.com/RFtcEC  Extracts numbers from a string read in,  the numbers separated by a space character.  What you're showing is more C-like than C++.

Comment: Careful there, @PaulMcKenzie . Note the `#include<conio.h>`. If you suggest anything even remotely like modern C++, the compiler may hit you with a cane and call you a whipper-snapper.

Comment: You are accessing `ach` out of bounds!

Comment: @user4581301 Didn't concentrate on the headers so much.  The point was that there is no need to write code like this to extract integers from a string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nope. The question is pretty deep in X-Y space. Your answer's about the best that can be given, I just don't know if OP's tool chain is up to it.

Answer (score 0):

Oups your code is not really optimized and is mainly C with the exception of `cin.getline`. But your real problem is that with `int ach[10][1]`, `ach` is a 2D array of size 10x1, so `ach[i][1]` may not be what you expect because you should define `int ach[10][2]` to safely use it. The rules for array indexes computing give `&(ach[i][1]) == &ach[0][0] + i*1 + 1` so you are actually accessing `ach[i+1][0]` with a possible *past end array* access if i is 9.

Moreover, at first access, ach[0][1] is used without being first initialized.

So your ach definition should be:

```
int ach[10][2] = {0};
```